# select specific name zip files and unzip it to respective folder using python

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I have a directory which is having list of different name zip files. I want to unzip them and copy the files to their respective locations.

Suppose below is my directory location:

```
F:\Download_Data\myData\
```

It has below set of zip files:

```
ABC_EMPLOYEECODES20190513.txt.zip
ABC_EMPLOYEECODES20190516.txt.zip
ABC_EMPLOYEECODES20190521.txt.zip
ABC_EMPLOYEECODES20190528.txt.zip
```

and

```
ABC_EMPLOYEEDETAILS20190413.txt.zip
ABC_EMPLOYEEDETAILS20190416.txt.zip
```

I would like to read above directory and unzip/extract these files and place them at respective location as depending upon the file names:

```
ABC_EMPLOYEECODES20190513.txt
ABC_EMPLOYEECODES20190516.txt
ABC_EMPLOYEECODES20190521.txt
ABC_EMPLOYEECODES20190528.txt
```

Above given files should go to this location: `'F:\EmployeeCode\myData\'`

And below given files should go to this location: `'F:\EmployeeDetails\myData\'`

```
ABC_EMPLOYEEDETAILS20190413.txt
ABC_EMPLOYEEDETAILS20190416.txt
```

Here's the code which I am trying to perform the task:

```
import zipfile
import os
zipfilepath="F:/Download_Data/myData"
unzipfilepath1 = "G:/testfolder1"
unzipfilepath2 = "G:/testfolder2"

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(zipfilepath):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith("ABC_EMPLOYEECODES"):
           filepath1=os.path.join(root,file)
           with zipfile.ZipFile(filepath1,"r") as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall(unzipfilepath1)
        elif file.startswith("ABC_EMPLOYEEDETAILS"):
            filepath2=os.path.join(root,file)
            with zipfile.ZipFile(filepath1,"r") as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall(unzipfilepath2)
```

It's working fine now. any suggestion most welcome.

Comment: anyway you must provide what you tried

Comment: Python has built-in libraries for your needs, and you should be able to find simpler examples online. Once you have some code that you think should work, post it here so we can help fix the errors.